# Making several classes with different values for their attributes: any way to avoid having to make several __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, subclass

I'm making a text based adventure game in Python 3, and i need to make classes for the different enemy types. Each enemy type will have 5 attributes (current hp, max hp, attack, speed, and accuracy). I'm wondering if there is any way to make these classes *without having to write several inits containing the same attribute declarations*, if that makes sense. So i could have a superclass or something containing this `__init__`

```
    def __init__(self, hp, attack, speed, accuracy):

        #defines stats for the enemy
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.currenthp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.speed = speed
        self.accuracy = accuracy
```

and just sort of "copy it" into the different enemy type classes. Is there any way to do this, or will i have to type out a different superclass containing this init for each enemy type?

Comment: Do you actually need different classes per enemy type? Do they change behavior or only the values? Think whether inheritance or composition is what would be better suited for your purpose

Comment: You could pack the parameters in a separate class (preferably a data class) and the unpacking (if needed) can be done in a commonly inherited method called from `__init__`.

Comment: @UnholySheep Right now i only need to change the attribute values, but i would like to keep it flexible in case i decide to change more between each enemy type.

Comment: @MichaelButscher How would i go about doing that?

Comment: Since Python 3.7 there is the [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module to help with class creation.

Comment: I agree with @UnholySheep, this almost sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you've described, you don't actually *need* sub-classes, you could just have different instances of the `Enemy` class. If you're determined to have multiple classes, you could bake the attributes into the `__init__` method. Here's both options...

#### Instantiation

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, hp, attack, speed, accuracy):
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.speed = speed
        self.accuracy = accuracy

Warrior = Enemy(100, 5, 7, 6)
Dragon = Enemy(500, 8, 2, 4)
```

#### Subclasses

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, hp, attack, speed, accuracy):
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.speed = speed
        self.accuracy = accuracy

class Warrior(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(100, 5, 7, 6)

class Dragon(Enemy):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(500, 8, 2, 4)
```

I hope that answers your question. I would do the first method until I really needed more functions specific to each class. From the outset I'm not sure what else a `Dragon` would be able to do more specifically than an `Enemy`. Comment below if you're confused.

---

**Edit**: Just thought of a third thing you could do as a modification of the instantiation method.

The problem with the instantiation method is that if you want multiple of one type then you have to keep redeclaring them with their "Enemy" attributes. But you could avoid this by using the `__call__` method.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, hp, attack, speed, accuracy):
        self.hp = hp
        self.attack = attack
        self.speed = speed
        self.accuracy = accuracy

    def __call__(self):
        return Enemy(self.hp, self.attack, self.speed, self.accuracy)

Warrior = Enemy(100, 5, 7, 6)
Dragon = Enemy(500, 8, 2, 4)
```

And then you could create new instances of `Warrior` or `Dragon` without using `Enemy(...)`:

```
warrior1 = Warrior()
warrior2 = Warrior()
dragon1 = Dragon()

assert warrior1 is not warrior2
assert dragon1 is not Dragon
assert isinstance(dragon1, Enemy)
```

Comment: I believe this was what i was looking for! I didn't know you could pass values like ints directly into the ``__init__``. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand, you want one superclass "Enemy" and for each subclass of "Enemy" you want for example, "Warrior", "Dragon", "Knight"; each enemy has hp, attack, accuracy stats, but the Warrior may have different attributes and methods than a dragon like flying. In this case I would check out this article about inheritance. Inheritance allows you to create just one superclass and have those attributes 'inherited' by each subclass: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp

Ex:

```
class Subclass(Superclass):
  def __init__(self, SubclassAttribute1, SubclassAttribute2):
    super().__init__(SuperclassAttribute1, SuperclassAttribute2)
```